# Firebase not invoking OnChildChanged Events

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Given the following DB scheme:
[image]

I wish to listen for any mHotZoneRecord change. to do, i did as follows:

```
mDBRefUsers = mDatabase.getReference("/users/");
mDBRefUsers.child("mHotZoneRecord").addChildEventListener(new HotZoneNotification(this));
```

and somewhere else during the code, implemented `HowZoneNotification` class

```
class HotZoneNotification extends TableSyncInfo
        implements ChildEventListener {
      OnChildChanged();
      OnChildAdded();
}
```

The problem is im not getting the OnChildChanged event whatsoever.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `onChildChanged()` will only be invoked if a change is made to one of the existing nodes under `/users`.

Comment: did you not implement these methods?  maybe we can help more if you show the entire implementation of `HotZoneNotification`

Comment: These have been implemented, but removed by me, as in my opinion not important to this example, as the callback itself not invoked, and mDbLatitute and mdbLongtitude do change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set listener on users not on mHotZoneRecord .. to set the listener to it you have to access to '-Kt8Y......' so to do what you want you have to do these changes.

```
mDBRefUsers = mDatabase.getReference("/users/");
mDBRefUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           // dataSnapshot .. hold list of users keys .. now you can hold it to set your listener
           for(DataSnapshot dataSnapShot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                  mDBRefUsers.child(dataSnapShot1.getValue(String.class))
                  .child("mHotZoneRecord")
                  .addChildEventListener(new HotZoneNotification(this));
                  // this equals users.child("-Kt8YIIAEH6EKXIbh3YN").child("mHotZoneRecord").[YOU LINSTER]

           }
   }
```

The wrong you did is that you tell database that there is a child called "mHotZoneRecord" in users branch 
like this pic [image]

So what i did is that i entered in 'users' branch then i got all keys "Kt8YIIAEH6EKXIbh3YN - Kt8A ...." then i set listener on "mHotZoneRecord" child which contained in keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer? but why do you use SingleValueEvent rather than regular valueEvent which will be invoked each time?

Comment: because you just need to access to keys so you do not need to set event listener on keys ..